# Recursive method to calculated powers using repeated squaring

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote this recursive method:

```
public class Main {

    public static int p(int x, int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
            return p(x, (n / 2)) * p(x, (n / 2));
        else
            return x * p(x, (n - 1 / 2)) * p(x, (n - 1 / 2));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Main.p(2, 3));

    }

}
```

However, upon running it I'm getting a StackOverflowError - I looked this up and it seems that the recursion is "too deep" and the stack can't handle it. But I'm confused since when n=0, the recursion should cease since that is a base case. How can I correct this issue?

Comment: `n - 1 / 2` doesn't do what you think it does. `(n - 1) / 2` does ;).

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: I also just spotted another error I made,  if (n == 0) should be  if (n == 1)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it should return 1.

Comment: Java will not infer that `p(x, (n / 2)) == p(x, (n / 2))` and only calculate it once. I suggest you put these results into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of correct parenthesis, i.e. make sure your brackets do what you want them to.

```
public class Main
{
    public static int p(int x, int n) 
    {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
            return p(x, (n / 2)) * p(x, (n / 2));
        else
            return x * p(x, ((n - 1) / 2)) * p(x, ((n - 1) / 2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Main.p(2, 3));
    }
```

NOTE: notice the (n - 1) in brackets. Also note that when n == 0 we return 1 as any number to the power of 0 is 1.

Also, you would be better off not calling the method statically (techincally it's 'slopppy programming').

You would be better off instantiating the class as an object and calling the method that way.

Comment: Yup, I agree. But I'm just playing around with it hence my use of static here (writing less code to test it out)

Comment: I also just spotted another error I made, if (n == 0) should be if (n == 1)

Comment: Good to see you are trying to solve your own problems, I managed to overlook this. However, (n == 0) was correct, but this should return 1 not 0 (which you have) as any number to the power of 0 is 1. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it should return 1, exactly.